# C++ header and implementation, (why) is it not automatically handled by the IDE/compiler?

Tags: c++, header-files

In C++, your classes are often divided into two parts, being the header-file and the actual implementation. In my (unexperienced) opinion, this is awful. It requires me to do all sorts of unnecessary book-keeping, clutters up my project directory and goes against everything I've learned about software development (double implementation). Languages where you only deal with the implementation, such as Java or Python, are much nicer to work with.

I've always learned that the reason to use them was to significantly decrease compilation time. However, wouldn't a modern IDE (CLion in my case) or even the compiler be smart enough to either:

- Keep some sort of "shadow"-header file, which would automatically be updated whenever a definition is changed in the implementation?
- Automatically split it into the header and implementation during compile time, allowing you to only have to deal with one file? (Something that [Lazy C++](http://www.lazycplusplus.com) seems to do)

Or are there any plugins available that offer this kind of behaviour? C++ modules also seem to offer a solution to this problem, but their current status/support is unclear to me and to make matters worse there seem to be two competing standards (Clang's and Microsoft's).

Comment: If you know how better this should work, write a paper to the C++ standard committee, describing the details of how it should work. I'm sure everybody would benefit from this.

Comment: Yes it sucks. It's there for historical reasons, and you can't easily change it without breaking decades of stuff.

Comment: The way it works in C++ is even more awful than you think. That bad part is that sometimes you need to write separate declarations because of name recognition rules leave no room for workarounds. But the worst part is that writing implementation in separate translation units is one of the main reasons for long build times as well as for reduced codegen quality, however there is a workaround: write header-only libraries.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk, look, I realize that the people coming up with the C++-specifications are far smarter and more experienced than me, so I'm not under any assumptions that I'll be able to come up with better solutions than them. However, something like the Lazy C++ mentioned seems like it wouldn't be to hard to implement in an IDE, even if it would only work in 50% of the cases, so I'm curious as for why they are not used that often. Same goes for modules, which were already proposed in C++0X, but apparently there are reasons as to why it is still not in the standard.

Comment: With the source (implementation) in a separate module, the compiler only has to compile the implementation once, then link it.  With everything in the same file (like Java), the code in the header gets translated each time it is included into a source.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not that simple. Header/source file separation C++ inherited from C due to preprocessor, that both share. Automatic generation of a header file is not possible in general, first of all that separation is not trivial, second header file often has preprocessor code that manually written and generates compilation code. Third almost all templated code goes to a header file due to process of compilation and rules of visibility. Changing all of that would require breaking compatibility with existing code, amount of which is significant and nobody wants to do that. More easy would be to create yet another language (like D) but many people would not want to migrate due to various reasons. We know that committee is working on modules and if they manage to make them work without breaking compatibility, that would be helpful for many of us. But again this is not trivial task at all, the way you describe it would only work in certain environments (when you limit yourself) but cannot be applied to everybody.